# What chiral point group is a cube twisted $\pi$/4?

Tags: group-theory, geometry, finite-groups

The structure looks like

[image]

where all sides have the same length. The structure originates from a cube twisted $\pi$/4 perpendicular to one plane. Seen from above

[image]

Point wise this is not a chiral group, if just the points in the joints are considered. An idea is to put additional points in the middle of each rod. This resembles the intended application where one type of atoms are in the corners and another type of atoms are in the middle of each rod.

Comment: Pointwise this is an achiral point group... How should a question be asked about this?

Comment: It's a bit difficult to understand exactly what you're asking -- can you try writing some more text to explain what it is you want to know? The symmetry group of the figure seems just to be $D_{2\cdot 4}$ (generated by a 90° rotation around the obvious axis, and a 180° rotation around a line connecting the midpoints of two opposite twisted edges); there are no orientation-reversing symmetries, so "chiral" or "achiral" should not make any difference.

Comment: If that is the seen-from-above diagram then it's not the case that 'all sides have the same length'; the edges on the upper ('outer') square have length $\sqrt2$ times the edges of the lower square.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki This is just a projection effect in the photo. All sides are the same length, in this case similar matches.

Comment: One cube does not a point group make. The shape given doesn't tile space in any 'natural' way by translations; the bottom and top square tilings aren't 'compatible'.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki This can not form a lattice sideways and is not intended to do so either. Vertically it can after rotating $\pi$/8. It is a type of one dimensional crystal, or tube.

Comment: In that case, it looks like what you're looking at is a $C_8$ [axial point group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_groups_in_three_dimensions#The_seven_infinite_series_of_axial_groups) .

Comment: @StevenStadnicki There are three axises, one allow 90 degrees rotation and the other two 180. It seems to be a $D_{4d}$. WIkipedia mentions it as a square antiprism or twisted prism https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_antiprism#Twisted_prism .